# Possibility for EAN13+5 addon barcode scanning in iOS?

Tags: ios, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have been searching all over the internet for a solution to my problem but cannot find a solution anywhere so this is my last hope:

Is it possible to scan a EAN13 barcode with an Addon5 barcode (used on books and magazines) in iOS somehow?

All the libraries I looked at are very much outdated (probably because of native iOS support for barcodes). However the native iOS support does not seem to support EAN13+5 barcodes. Or very expensive. If possible I need a free solution for this app.

The barcode looks like the one in this image:

[image: EAN13] [image: ADDON5]

Comment: https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC

Comment: @shallowThought the github page lists EAN-8 and EAN-13 but not EAN-13+5 - are you sure it is supported?

Comment: I can build the project and see some references to `kBarcodeFormatUPCEANExtension` and `UPC/EAN extension` but by default it does not scan the EAN-13+5 barcode. So is there additional code needed for this @shallowThought?

Comment: Ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Not sure how this was resolved @JamesParker. In the end I found someone who built it for me. I do know it was possible in the end, just not sure how.